# Torsocks curl vs curl --socks5

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, torsocks

On my linux box, I have both Tor and Tor browser bundle installed and running.

I was wondering which of those two is to be preferred (in the sense of being the most robust to potential "anonymity leaks", the fastest, and the "most logical"):

```
torsocks curl http://example.com
```

or

```
curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9150 http://example.com
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use either

```
torsocks curl http://example.com
```

or

```
curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:9150 http://example.com
```

to ensure that DNS requests aren't leaked.

Comment: The question is asking which of those two is preferred. Listing them out again doesn't really answer the question asked.

Comment: This answer is misleading. It should be deleted, I think, because fixing it would make it duplicate the other answer. Yes?

Comment: @AndrewLott Note that `--socks5-hostname` is very different than `--socks5`.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use `torsocks curl` here, because `curl --socks5` does **NOT** use the given SOCKS proxy to resolve DNS name. See [torsocks documentation](https://code.google.com/p/torsocks/) for more specifics. Also, you can use `usewithtor [application]` instead of `torsocks [application]`.

Answer (score 1):

ONLY *curl **--socks5-hostname** 127.0.0.1:9150 http://example.com* because to not-leak-dns you must not doing DNS queries =) and --socks5-hostname clause forces NOT using resolvers at all, and passing the raw hostname to the proxy to resolve. Forget 'torificators' if a program/library supports total avoiding DNS queries.